# Can I search dB for list of items and return their IDs respectively?

Tags: java, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a data table like "animals" and I want to search for 5 animals at once (open connection once) and get their IDs respectively then close the connection one time only - for the sake of performance - instead of opening connection everytime and search for one animal and then close the connection and redo this times.
Is there a way to do this

Comment: You can write queries that do things like search in a range, or provide a list of things you want to match (example here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#collection-parameters ). If you just want to return the IDs, here's how you do that: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-subset

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a **caching solution**. So when we are using an ORM library like Hibernate, it will automatically enable 1st level cache that's available through the particular hibernate session. Also if you need you can use 2nd level cache(Ex: EH Cache) that's available throughout the entire application. (this will need manual implementation)
If the application level cache is not possible you can go with a database cache like Redis. But in your case, I guess application-level cache will do the trick.